# how to keep a google spreadsheet sorted by date

Tags: sorting, automation, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a Google spreadsheet that lists expenses in rows, as in:

```
Date          Amount
2014 12 24    $34
2014 12 22    $83
```

I'd like to keep the entries reverse-sorted by date (i.e. most recent first).

The obvious idea is to select `Sort sheet by column A, Z->A` from the `Data` menu (column A stores the dates). However, this sorts the header row (`Date       Amount`) along with the actual data rows.

My current solution is to temporarily replace `Date` with some made-up date in the far future, then `Sort sheet by column A, Z->A`, then restore the `Date` header. It's cumbersome and a bit silly.

Is there a way to "Sort rows 2~infinity by column A, Z->A"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try 'fixing' the first row in the 'view' menu (freely translating). That should prevent the header row from shifting when you sort the column.

Comment: Just for the record: View - Freeze - 1 row is the correct translation

Answer (score 1):

Go to ***Data ==> Sort Range...***

Tick the ***Data has header row*** checkbox, choose the ***Sort By*** option from the list, and click ***Sort***.

That should sort your sheet, based on the column you selected, without affecting the header row.

Comment: In question there is: 'The obvious idea is to select Sort sheet by column A, Z->A'

Comment: @Outside_Box - indeed. let's hope google spreadsheets sorts date naturally in a recent-first fashion :) (i haven't tested this in a long time....)